# How To Access External IP Inside Own Network?

Tags: networking

This is my representation of our ip here in our home network.

Default Gateway - 192.168.1.1

Server - 192.168.1.4

External IP(Our ip with the help of whatsmyip.org) - 122.x.xx.xxx

I'm the one that is using the server what I want is to access our external ip even inside the same network, what is currently happening is when I type in the url our external ip which is 122.x.xx.xxx, the browser redirects me to my default gateway which is the configuration page of our router.

*Note: other computer(computer shop, mobile phone on 3G etc.) which is outside the network have access on our external ip, and they have access on the file that I put on there, for example they type on the url: 122.x.xx.xxx/SamplePHP the browser will display the PHP program that I created.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to setup port redirection for your webserver or get access to all resources on your internal network like you were in the internal network?

If the former, I would consult your router's manual for more details on how to setup port forwarding. Long story short, exposing your router's webserver to the outside world (at least on the default ports -- security in obscurity :)!) is a bad idea from a security perspective.

If the latter, you could look at setting up VPN to access internal network resources more securely (a really good idea if your webserver/web app is only setup to run plaintext traffic -- but this would only prevent MitM/sniffing over the Internet and not on your local network). I would consult your router's manual (again) for more details. For what it's worth you may have to setup port redirection via your router to achieve this if VPN support isn't built into the router.

Comment: I just want to be able to access 122.x.xx.xxx inside the network much more like how I access 192.168.1.4.

Comment: Ah, the other way around? I'm sorry for misunderstanding your question the first time.

This a bit tricky because I'm not sure how your router's webserver is serving data, but it might be possible via DNS/static routes/URL rewriting to achieve what you want. I wish I could say more (I need more details about your router in order to help).

Comment: My router is a SpeedSurf 504AN

Comment: Maybe this link will help you find the right settings for my router. http://setuprouter.com/router/pldt/speedsurf-504an/screenshots.htm